# ASP.NET Core Identity UserManager<ApplicationUser> -Error No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-identity

I am just trying to develop a sample project for authentication and authorization, and following the link

[ASP.NET Core MVC: Authentication and Role Based Authorisation with Identity](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Core-MVC-Authenticat-ef5942f5/sourcecode?fileId=168175&pathId=158158342)

When running the code, I get an error

[image]

Stack Trace:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +247    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'SampleAuthProject.Controllers.HomeController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +194    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +103    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

I think this error due to DI.

So in my startup.cs contains

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
public Startup()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    Configurations = builder.Build();
}
public IConfigurationRoot Configurations { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    try
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
               IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseIdentity();
}
```

My HomeController is

```
 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //userManager=new UserManager<ApplicationUser>();
        string userName =  userManager.GetUserName(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current);
        return View("Index",userName);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: No, userManager become null

Comment: can u post the entire error message as the image is cut from right side

Comment: sure, error message updated

Comment: @Jinesh Are you sure you are using a core project? those namespaces in the trace are from MVC 5. It appears you are trying to mix framework versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to mix framework versions.

The `Startup` is using both `IAppBuilder`, which is from *asp.net-mvc-5* and `IApplicationBuilder`, which is from the more recent *asp.net-core*.

Also, the exception message

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

is commonly associated with the vague messages that were returned from MVC 5 and Web.Api 2.*

This basically means that the Identity dependencies are not know to the dependency injection framework for that project, which is why it is unable to inject the dependencies into the controllers.

Either make sure that the project is in fact an *asp.net-core* project to be able to use *asp.net-core-identity*

[Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

Or use the correct version of Identity Framework for MVC 5.

[Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)